# TLSV1 and TLSV1.2 coexist issue in wireshark

Tags: tls, wireshark, spdy

I analysed an live camero's net traffic and found that the client uses both TLS1.0 and TLS1.2 in the handshakings while the server only uses TLS1.0.

How can the handshaking uses both TLSV1.0 and TLSV1.2?Is there a reason for doing so?

1.Is TLS1.0 is sufficiently secure?

2.It uses spdy with TLS1.0, can spdy help to make the transferring more secure?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Basically duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29314/what-is-the-significance-of-the-version-field-in-a-tls-1-1-clienthello-message . The *record* version in ClientHello is more or less the lowest offered and the *message* version is the highest requested. Once the server chooses and replies, everything else uses that version, or if it's too low the client aborts.

Comment: So the server only supports TLS1.0 if i understand it correctly. How about the security level of TLS1.0?Is it secure enough?

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44275/is-tls-1-0-sufficiently-secure-for-a-bank